# Not able to append <Script/> tag to <div> index.html react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, salesforce, salesforce-chatter

Hi I need to append below script to div tag in index.html of react. I am getting this script from backend API side

```html
<style type='text/css'>
       .helpButton .uiButton {
        background-color: #005290;
        font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
      }
    
       .helpButton .uiButton:focus {
        outline: 1px solid #005290;
      }
    </style>
    
    <script type='text/javascript' src='.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var initESW = async function (gslbBaseURL) {
        embedded_svc.settings.samplesplayHelpButton = true; 
        embedded_svc.settings.language = ''; 
        
        
        embedded_svc.settings.enabledFeatures = ['LiveAgent'];
        embedded_svc.settings.entryFeature = 'LiveAgent';

        try {

          await embedded_svc.init(
            'https://test--sample.my.salesforce.com',
            'https://sample-test.cs81.force.com/Surveys',
            gslbBaseURL,
            '111111111',
            'DDC_test',
            {
              baseLiveAgentContentURL: 'https://test.salesforceliveagent.com/content',
              deploymentId: '111111111',
              buttonId: '111111111',
              baseLiveAgentURL: 'https://test.salesforceliveagent.com/chat',
              eswLiveAgentDevName: 'test_event',
              isOfflineSupportEnabled: true
            }
          );
        }
        catch (error) {
          console.log(error)
        }
      };

      if (!window.embedded_svc) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src', 'https://test--sample.my.salesforce.com/embeddedservice/5.0/esw.min.js');
        s.onload = function () {
          initESW(null);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(s);
      } else {
        initESW('https://service.force.com');
      }
    </script>
```

**I am able to append above script to div tag of index.html react** .**but it not rendring on UI.**
I written below code for append data to index.html

```
var data = API call;
document.getElementById('webchat').innerHTML = data;
```

My index.html have div tag with id "webchat"

```
<div id="webchat"></div>
```